# The json extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration

Tags: php, json, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I install PHP5.6.0 on Ubuntu 13.10 x64 from this

```
https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5-5.6a
```

then I installed phpmyadmin when I am trying to lunch phpmyadmin I got this message

```
The json extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.
```

my PHP modules:

```
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dba
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib
```

[Zend Modules]
   Zend OPcache

then when i use this command to install `php-json`

```
sudo apt-get install php5-json
```

I got this

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
php5-json : Depends: phpapi-20121212
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get update` before?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are install PHP5 from a custom repo. I would remove PHP and remove that  repo.

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
sudo apt-get update
```

now install php

```
sudo apt-get install php5-common php5-json
```

Answer (score 2):

Below solution worked for me-

```
cd /etc/php5/mods-available
vi json.ini
```

In this file make below changes

```
priority=20
extension=json.so
```

Incase if json.ini file is not there, create the file with contents as

```
priority=20
extension=json.so
```

Comment: I needed two mores steps after doing this: 1) run "sudo php5enmod json", then 2) restart apache. With that, all was well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to me to be because of Ubuntu's default permissions for the php.ini files. It only allows Root to read/execute the directories holding the in files.

You can easily verify this by observing that when you execute:
    sudo php -m

You see all installed and enabled modules listed correctly.

The solution to this I have found on ubuntu distros is to:

```
sudo chmod a+rx /etc/php5/cli/
sudo chmod a+rx /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
sudo chmod a+rx /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/
```

Then you can easily verify by running:

```
php -m
```

Comment: Note that the chmod commands I have suggested add only Read and Execute permissions. Execute permissions is needed on directory to enable users to view the directory listing. I believe these permissions are safe, but I'm open to contrary information.

Comment: I should also add, the commands above only fix this for the use case of PHP from the command line. Apache uses a different php.ini file located in /etc/php5/apache2/

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after loading the installed modules `json` and `mcrypt`.

```
$ sudo php5enmod json && sudo php5enmod mcrypt $ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Go to http://yourserver/phpmyadmin and take a look to check if it works.